# Mails that were moved from the inbox to other folders in Outlook 365 do not show up in their new folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

After moving mails from the inbox to other folders, I do not see them anymore, yet, the number of unread mails (or if I change the settings of the folder, the number of all mails) is shown in the Outlook side menu next to the folder title:

[image]

And the folder does not show any mails at all.

[image]

> No elements were found that match the search criteria.

This German Microsoft forum entry [Mails disappear when moved in Outlook 2013](https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/outlook_com/forum/all/mails-verschwinden-beim-verschieben-in-outlook/8c1602c8-136e-40a5-8698-709da859fb8e?page=2) says that this should not happen anymore from Office 2016 on, but I even have `Microsoft® Outlook® für Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20332) 64 Bit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a guide on the net that I did not read well enough, and perhaps, this might help someone who gets lost a bit or needs a second hint.

1. No need to reinstall anything. Nothing is lost. The mails are only filtered out, likely by a very strange filter that you do not remember having set at all.
2. Click on the folder with the missing mails:

   - Either click "View" -> "View Settings"

   [image]

   - or click on the "Filter applied" text in the status bar in the bottom left:

   [image]

Then delete any filters you find in the four tabs, by clicking on the "Delete all" (in the screenshots: "Alles löschen") button on the bottom right wherever you have filters listed in the settings.

For me, it was not needed here:
[image]

Nor here:
[image]

But here:
[image]
[image]

See the Microsoft forum entry [Items disappear or are not visible in an Outlook folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/email-management/items-disappear-not-visible-outlook-folder#for-outlook-2010-and-later-versions).

Afterwards, you see the mails again, and the status bar changes to:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

About this issue, please do following steps to filter the unread email: click on your Inbox folder > click on the Search bar > in the Search tab, select Unread (see below picture). Here is an article for your reference:
[image]

Moreover, if you have turned on Focused Inbox feature, then please check if the unread messages is in the Other tab.

[image]

Comment: This was not a filter on the unread mail, see the screenshots in the other answer. Your answer might still help someone else with a filter on the unread.

Comment: I am sorry that my answer has some problems. I notice that you have post the correct answer. I would suggest that you mark yourself answer as "accepted answer". This kind behavior can help more people who also meet the same problems to notice your answer and solve the issue.

Comment: Done, forgot that, good point.